# Varying magnetic field creates varying electric field. Does constant magnetic field creates a constant electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields

Varying magnetic field creates varying electric field. Does constant magnetic field creates a constant electric field? If yes, an simple wire(like on picture, for example) with DC power will attractes\repel(depends on +-) ferromagnetics?

How do I imagine it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is one of Maxwell's equations:

$$-\frac{\partial{\vec{B}}}{\partial{t}} = \vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E}$$

It says that a time-varying magnetic field will always accompany a spatially-varying non-conservative electric field. (Not quite the same as saying it *creates* an electric field--I'm borrowing the language used [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction)-- but perhaps this is a minor linguistic point.)

If $\vec{B}$ is not time-varying, we won't see the non-conservative electric field $\vec{E}$ referenced here, but there is a *conservative* electric field outside the wire when a current is flowing. See [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61884/does-a-current-carrying-wire-produce-electric-field-outside) for further discussion.